# makeによってつくられたデータ構造の参照渡し

Tags: アルゴリズム, go

makeによってデータ構造の参照を作り、関数に参照を渡しデータの変更を行います。
以下のような出力になるのはなぜでしょうか？

https://play.golang.org/p/lOC49HmVcq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := make(map[string]int)
    set(a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func set(a map[string]int){
  for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
    a["key"]++
  }
  a = map[string]int{"key":1}
  fmt.Println(a)
}
```

出力
map[key:1]
map[key:10]

参照の値変更は最終的に`a = map[string]int{"key":1}`が適用されて、予想した出力は
map[key:1]
map[key:1]

だったのですが、、ロジックを教えてください。

Comment: 確かに **maps are a reference type** なのですが、そのコードでは map 型変数を `call by value(値渡し)` にしています。そのため、`set` 関数内で map の内容を変更することはできますが map 型変数自体を変更してもその有効範囲は `set` 関数ローカルになります。期待通りにするには https://play.golang.org/p/gUqoGQYsG8 の様に map 型変数を `call by reference(参照渡し)` にする必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mainとsetそれぞれに`println(&a)`という行を追加して、aのポインタを見ると別のアドレスになっていることが分かると思います。
すなわちset関数の引数を`a *map[string]int`にして、ポインタを渡すようにすると期待通りに動作します。
setの引数をポインタにした後にset内でのaのアドレスを確認する場合は、`println(a)`とすることに注意してください。